# how to find element of an Array that has the same property with element from another array and change it accordingly?

Tags: ios, swift

I have product class like the code below:

```
class Product {
    var productID = ""
    var hasBeenAddedToWishList = false
}
```

and then I have two arrays of product

```
let wishListedProduct = [productx,producty,productz] // from core data
let productList = [productx,producty,productz] // from server
```

[image]

I want to give filled love icon, if the user previously has added the product to the wishlist in core data.

so I want to make a looping between to arrays above, so if the product in the first index of `wishListedProduct` has the same ID with the first indeex of `productList`, then I need to change the property of `hasBeenAddedToWishList` to true. how to do that ?

I have tried with the code below but I can't get what I want

```
        for i in theWishListProducts {

                products.map {

                    if $0.productID == i.productID {
                        $0.hasBeenAddedToWishList = true
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
let wishListedProduct : [Product] = // whatever
let productList : [Product] = // whatever
let wishListedIds = wishListedProduct.map {$0.productID}
for product in productList {
    if wishListedIds.contains(product.productID) {
        product.hasBeenAddedToWishList = true
    }
}
```